# Is there any way to get the google keep extension working with the login-bug?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, brave, vivaldi

Every time I try to open the [google keep chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-chrome-extens/lpcaedmchfhocbbapmcbpinfpgnhiddi) it tells me to log-in, at the same time when I click "log-in" nothing happens. This happens on the Brave Beta-browser as well as on my secondary Browser Vivaldi. I have given it every single permission there is and am logged into my Google-account on the Browsers. On Google Chrome it works just fine. Is there any way to fix this issue on Brave Beta-browser?

Comment: Did you by any chance ever figure this one out? Been trying to get it to work forever, unsuccessfully.